# RabbitMQ Basic Consumer

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, .net-8.0

I'm consuming a RabbitMQ queue, but when using non-asynchronous operations, my consumption method only obtains one message, but in rabbit it indicates that they were all consumed? Is the rabbit's behavior like that? I used asynchronous operators and managed to get all messages from the queue.

```cs
    private IEnumerable<ReceivedPaymentViewModel> GetMessageQueue()
    {
        var payments = new List<ReceivedPaymentViewModel>();

        using var channel = _rabbitConnection.CreateChannel();
        channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "PaymentProcessedQueue", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false,
            arguments: null);

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
            
        consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
        {
            var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            var messages = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ReceivedPaymentViewModel>(message);

            if (messages != null)
                payments.Add(messages);
        };

        channel.BasicConsume(queue: "PaymentProcessedQueue", autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);
            
        channel.Close();

        return payments;
    } 


//Get messages in the RabbitMQ queue
```

Comment: I would suggest you use masstransit

Comment: When you are using a Consumer, the broker will push the messages to you based on QoS/prefetch. Normaly with a service and a "while(true)" or kicked of as a BackgroundService. The code above is therefore not optimal. The consumer is meant to be constructed and started (calling BasicConsume), and you need to handle the message beeing sent to you in the .Received()-callback.  
Are you able to tell something about what kind of logic you want to achieve? then its easier to give you a good example of how to do it.

Comment: I just wanted to understand why my method doesn't consume all the messages in my queue (sometimes it consumes 0 or 3).

Answer (score 1):

You're auto-acknologing your queue items as stated here:

```
channel.BasicConsume(queue: "PaymentProcessedQueue", *autoAck: true*, consumer: consumer);
```

So, once a message was read by your consumer, it will get set to "done that".

Change it to autoAck: false

Instead insert into your Received-Method the following:

```
consumer.Received += async (model, ea) => {
  ...
  await channel.BasicAckAsync(args.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
}
```

This will only ack a message once your method was successfully exited.